# Can LM35 temperature sensor be used to measure temperatures in bone in an in vitro setting? are they comparable to K type thermocouples?

Tags: thermocouple, arduino-uno, lm35

I belong to the medical field. I have zero knowledge about electronics.
For my thesis, where I will be measuring temperature within the bone during drilling, I am required to use a temperature sensor of diameter not more than 0.8-1mm with decent accuracy (0.1°), and low margin of error.
From what I read, a K-type thermocouple seems like the choice of sensor. But I was advised to use a LM35 sensor with Arduino Nano.
Please throw some light on how to select, comparison, and the advantages and disadvantages of each.

Comment: Don't confuse resolution and accuracy.

Comment: If your main goal is to do the bone drilling rather than to develop a system, and you can use a thermocouple, and you can *get* a suitable thermocouple with a suitable commercial readout -- **stop**.  Get the parts, finish your thesis.  Do you want to figure out how to drill bone, or do you want to mess with clever ways to measure bone temperature?

Comment: https://www.omega.co.uk/temperature/z/thermocouple-rtd.html

Answer (score 6):

An LM35 is an electronic component. To see the characteristics we refer to a [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm35.pdf). Towards the end you'll find the mechanical drawings. The smallest available package is the epoxy TO-92 package, which will fit in a 5.5mm ID protection tube. If you look at small or hypodermic tubing you'll get some idea of the minimum OD (outer diameter) of tubing required, somewhere around 5.75mm, **way** more than 1mm.

Thermocouples are made in an enormous range of sizes and shapes, and you can readily find 1.0mm or even 0.8mm diameter probes. See manufacturer's data for specifications. You may have trouble finding accuracy numbers because it depends a lot on the application.

Aside from the mechanical characteristics, we have thermal characteristics. A <1mm probe will minimally affect the material being measured. A small thermocouple will have a very fast response time so there will be not much lag between a change in temperature and the resulting electrical signal. The LM35 being huge and encased in plastic, will be very sluggish in comparison.

So the LM35, as shown in the datasheet, can't possibly meet your size requirement.

---

On the other hand, the LM35 is trivially easy to interface with accuracy (measurement of the junction of the device, not necessarily measurement of the desired external material) that will meet the data sheet specifications. The premium version has a guaranteed accuracy of +/-0.5°C at 25°C, which deteriorates as you deviate from that reference temperature. Pretty good by semiconductor sensor standards but definitely not 0.1°C. If you calibrate them individually at a reference temperature they'll probably stay put, at least until the first time you autoclave them. But just about anyone can get them to work.

A thermocouple, to provide similar accuracy will require well-designed signal conditioning circuitry that has microvolt stability, and a cold junction sensor that provides significantly higher accuracy and stability than the desired system accuracy (you can't blow your entire error budget on the cold junction sensing). 0.1°C at body temperature represents about 4uV, which is **not** trivial to deal with, even with modern components. The cold junction sensor also has to be isothermal with the Chromel-copper and Alumel-copper junctions to significantly higher accuracy and stability than the desired system accuracy. And any connectors have to avoid introducing thermal EMFs that would degrade the reading too much. All in all, non-trivial even for a very experienced engineer.

Comment: You should be able to get a commercial thermocouple data logger for this job.

Comment: Well answered. However if for your project, your design could affect Human Life or success of a surgery in any way, You must study temperature sensing significant detail. Additionally you team up with a some people with expertise to define right failsafe measures. For mission critical applications where a human life could be affected by an invalid reading or no reading during a surgery, you would have to design redundancy at multiple levels and account for very rare failure modes known to a few people in that feild.

Comment: As the other comments indicate,  you should buy a commercial system to do this, however before you can do that you need to determine what your real requirements are. Start by studying data on commercial systems that appear to come close to your initial thoughts, and make sure you understand what each and every term really means. Preferably instruments and sensors that are aimed specifically at your type of application (medical). If your experimentation will involve only animals you may be able to compromise on some of the requirements that experimentation on human subject would demand.

Comment: agree with just about everything, but would consider a small thermistor to see if I could find one that is acceptable before moving over to a thermocouple -- unless planning to buy a complete thermocouple system.

Comment: @ScottSeidman Sure, there are thermistors available in that size range.. and smaller.. with good accuracy and aimed at the medical field (eg. catheters). A DVM may be sufficient to read them (assuming self-heating isn't too great).

Answer (score 0):

I would think that the thermal characteristics of the LM35 package would be too slow to effectively measure increased bone temperature during drilling.  By the time you knew the bone was getting too hot, the bone would be dead.

You need something in a very small package with minimal thermal mass.